# Python strategies for handing categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

I am currently working on a `binary classification` task where the class is `imbalanced`.

I have the following `categorical` attributes with different levels:

```
time_slot: 8 levels
product_type: 3 levels
state: 40 levels
due_day: 6 levels (Mon - Sat)
lead_time: numerical in days (0-100)
```

Now, I am planning to use three algorithms to start with:

```
Logistic Regression, Decision Tree and Random Forest
```

I am confused as to what sort of encoding strategy is best when it comes to categorical variables?

```
LabelEncoder, OneHot, BinaryEncoding?
```

Also, I am thinking of creating bins for `lead_time`

any pointers/tips will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The best option for encoding - `OneHot`, because if you use `Label encoding` you indicate that categorical values are comparable(**for example label 1 < label 2**), which most probably it's not true. `One hot encoding` create columns for each specific value in the column, moreover, these columns are linearly independent, so you don't create fake order between categorical values. Unfortunately, you got a lot of columns so learning of algorithms could be greedy for time and resource.

More details you will find [there](https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd)

Comment: Thanks. If I use `OHE`, the columns will increase but what sort of algorithm will work on such sparse data?

Comment: Not a simple answer. If you use ```OHE```, you could learn the algorithm by chunk of data frame. Another option's  ```custom``` encoding, but it's the most robust way.  Also you could try other options of encoding https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02